# javascript missing ) argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments

I'm getting this error with this javascript can anyone help me figure out what i'm doing wrong?

```
$(this).prepend('<a class="booknow2 sidelink sidelinkNew" href="javascript:__doPostBack('SetSess','')"><img src="../../images1/button/leftEdge.png" width="4" height="35" style="float:left; margin:0; padding:0;" alt="book now" /><img src="../../images1/button/rightEdge.png" width="4" height="35" style="float:right; margin:0; padding:0;" alt="book now" /><span>Check availability &raquo;</span></a>');
```

It's giving me the error

```
missing ) after argument list
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: Look at the code highlighting applied here. See the error? ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you need to escape some single quotes in there:

```
... __doPostBack(\'SetSess\',\'\') ...
```

Comment: Thanks should of seen that really!

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape enclosed quotes like this:

```
__doPostBack(\'SetSess\',\'\')
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for your information, but there is a better syntax then to prepend the whole thing as a huge HTML fragment. You can construct the whole thing with jQuery from scratch:

```
var anchor = $('<a>', {
    'class': 'booknow2 sidelink sidelinkNew', 
    // Try to use event handlers instead - inline event handlers are *bad*
    href: "javascript:__doPostBack('SetSess','')"
}).prependTo(this); 

$('<img>', {
    'width': '4',
    'height': '35',
    'alt': 'book now',
    'src': '../../images1/button/rightEdge.png'
}).css({
    // Try to use CSS instead - add a class 
    // and define the CSS in a separate stylesheet
    'float': 'left',
    'margin': 0,
    'padding': 0,
}).appendTo(anchor);

$('<span>', {
    html: 'Check availability &raquo;'
}).appendTo(anchor);
```

Comment: That's the jQuery way. +1 The `attr('href', …)` can be replaced by `click(function() {…})` to make it even more idiomatic.